# To disable Get Method if Sensitive Information is passed

Tags: model-view-controller, get, asp.net-mvc-routing

Our Application (MVC Based) accepts user payment information update request over GET method.Default method used by the application is POST.
Currently if we pass any sensitive information over a GET Method via Querystring, then Request sucessfully works.The reason is that it hits the same Edit Action method in Controller

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateRequest(true)]
public ActionResult Edit (parameters)
```

But what we want is that Any request with sensitive information (like Credit Card etc.) sent over a GET method should be rejected by the application.
Anyhow can we reject GET method through Routing if sensitive information is passed? Please suggest valid approach.

My current route that calls Action is mentioned below:

```
routes.MapRoute("ChargeInformation", "ChargeInformationt.aspx/{seq}", new { controller = "Payment", action = "Edit", seq = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 0):

Routing's only responsibility is to map URLs to route values and from route values back to URLs. It is a separate concern than authorizing the request. In fact, the built-in routing extension methods (`MapRoute`, `MapPageRoute`, and `IgnoreRoute`) completely ignore the incoming query string.

For request authorization, MVC has an `IAuthorizationFilter` interface that you can hook into. You can also (optionally) combine it with an attribute to make it run conditionally on specific action methods, as shown below.

In this case, you just want to reject specific query string key names that are passed into the request. It is unclear what action you wish to take in this case, so I am just setting to HTTP 403 forbidden as an example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DisallowQueryStringKeysAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> keysSplit;

    public DisallowQueryStringKeysAttribute(string keys)
    {
        this.keysSplit = SplitString(keys);
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var queryStringKeys = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys;

        // If any of the current query string keys overlap with the non-authorized keys
        if (queryStringKeys.Intersect(this.keysSplit, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any())
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

            // You must set the result property to a handler to run to tell the 
            // framework that the filter should do something other than run the 
            // action method. In this case, we just set it to an empty result, 
            // which implements the null object pattern. You could (if so inclined), 
            // make a class to set the status code or do something else               
            // (such as redirect) to indicate that the request is invalid.
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
        }
    }

    private string[] SplitString(string original)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
        {
            return new string[0];
        }

        var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                    let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                    where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                    select trimmed;
        return split.ToArray();
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateRequest(true)]
[DisallowQueryStringKeys("creditCard, password")]
public ActionResult Edit (string creditCard, string password)
```